# Can't plot cobweb for a value bigger than the fixed point

Tags: plotting

I have the following question:

1) Let X be a set of real numbers bigger than zero. f:X -> X and is defined by $f(x)=x^2 -x +0.5$.

So from the equation, I know the fixed points are approximately $s = 0.293$ and $s' = 1.707$.

If I want to illustrate my answer using a cobweb diagram for what happens to $f^n (x)$ as n tends to infinity when:

> a) $0 < x < s = f^n (s)$ converge to $u$
>
> b) $s < x < s' = f^n (s)$ converge to $u$
>
> c) $x > s' = f^n (x)$ doesn't tend to $u$, I think it diverges? Please correct me if wrong!

I did try to plot $a$ and $b$, it was easy, but I can't seem to plot $c$.

Would really appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Please show us how you plotted a) and b).

Comment: Welcome to our community. Soon some of our users will be available to help you.

Comment: is this a mathematica (software) quesiton?

Comment: @george2079 yes!

Comment: @bills for a), f[s_] := s^2 - s + 0.5;
Manipulate[Cobweb[f, 1.2, s, 15], {s, 0, 0.2929}]

Comment: @bills and b), Manipulate[Cobweb[f, 2.0, s, 15], {s, 0.2929, 1.7071}]

Comment: @LMC Thanks! :)

Comment: Cobweb does not seem to be a defined function? Can you provide its definition?

Comment: @bills It's the set of all positive numbers I guess? I think I got confused about 'defined functions'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
f[x_] = N[x^2 - x + 1/2]
Show[Plot[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 2}],
 ListPlot[
  Partition[Sequence @@ {#, #} & /@ NestList[f, 1., 10], 2, 1],
  Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

It does indeed diverge for start value greater than `u'`

```
Show[
 ListPlot[
  Partition[
   Sequence @@ {#, #} & /@ NestList[f, 1.7072, 13], 2, 1],
  Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 12}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Is `Flatten` necessary? More interesting is the starting point of 1.708 in your first `PlotRange`.

Comment: @rewi you are right, flatten isn't needed.  It converges to the  0.29 solution for any start point less than the upper stationary point. (It again diverges for a start less than `-1/Sqrt[2]` )

Comment: The starting points of 1.7 and 1.708 make very clear the problem. Very nicely done.

Answer (score 3):

I have voted for george2079. I post this to illustrate the behaviour in relation to the fixed points using arrows and step animation:

```
f[x_] := x^2 - x + 0.5
roots = {x, x} /. Solve[f[x] == x, x]
nf[x_, n_] := 
 Catenate[{{##}, {#2, #2}} & @@@ 
   NestList[{#[[2]], f[#[[2]]]} &, {x, f[x]}, n]]
Manipulate[
 Module[{arrows = {Red, Arrowheads[{{0, 0}, {0.03, 0.6}, {0, 1}}], 
       Arrow[##]} & /@ Partition[nf[c, n], 2, 1]},
  ListAnimate[
   Table[Plot[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 2.5}, PlotRange -> Table[{0, 2.5}, 2],
     Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.03], Point[{c, f[c]}], 
       Point[roots], Green, PointSize[0.02], Point[roots], 
       arrows[[1 ;; step]]}, Frame -> True, 
     AspectRatio -> Automatic], {step, 1, Length[arrows]}]]]
 , {c, 0, 2}, {n, Range[5]}]
```

[image]